# How do I return this variable using if statements?

Tags: c#, boolean

I know this might be a silly question, with an easy answer, but after an hour of searching the internet I could not find a way to do this;

```
    public bool GetCollision(int x, int y)
    {
        bool isPassable;

        if (x < 0 || x >= 20)
        {
            isPassable = false;
        }

        if (y < 0 || y >= 20)
        {
            isPassable = true;
        }

        return isPassable;
    }
```

On the second-to-last line it says that isPassable is unassigned... yet clearly I assign to it in the if statements. There must be some fundamental misunderstanding of "if" statements on my part.

So, how can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the value of `isPassable` if, for example, x = 5 and y = 5 ?

Comment: Another function altogether handles that. I'm implementing the collision (trying to at least) from Microsoft's Platformer Starter Kit.

Comment: Yes ok, but C# compiler requires a value for each possible case. If you're sure that those cases will never happen just initialize isPassable with true or false, or maybe if you don't fall in your expected cases, just throw an exception...

Comment: Google is your friend, for 'unassigned variable c#' you get first link to SO with Q and A, exactly the same!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because it doesn't have a default value set explicitly. Set isPassable to False by default and you're done.

---

Also you can do something like this:

```
return (!(x < 0 || x >= 20) && (y < 0 || y >= 20))
```

EDIT: The above solution would only work if an AND relationship would exist between your IFs.

Comment: Your return value expression is wrong. For example with x=-1 and y=-1 returns false while the OP method would return true.

Comment: You're right, there isn't an AND relationship between his IFs

Answer (score 4):

What is the result of this function if `x == 10` and `y == 10`? You have not defined what that result would be, and that is why the compiler is complaining.  In this example, the first `if` statement would evaluate to `false`, and nothing would happen. Then the second `if` statement would evaluate to `false`, and the function would try to return with no value assigned to `isPassable`.

Answer (score 3):

If none of `If` conditions evaluate to True, the variable will have nothing to return.

So, assign a default value to `isPassable`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are conditions under which the variable is not assigned at all. For instance, if x and y are both 0, the routine will return an unassigned variable. That is a no-no.

To clarify, the problem is not that there is no initial assigment (like `isPassable = false;`) but that the compiler warns you that you may have forgotten to check some conditions.

A construct like

```
bool isPassable;
if (...)
    isPassable = true;
else
    isPassable = false;
return isPassable;
```

would have been OK!

Answer (score 2):

`"isPassable is Unassigned"` Compiler is complaining because what if neither  `IF` condition is satisfied . So you need to assign a value to it while declaring it like:-

```
 isPassable=false;
```

Comment: That should be "what if **neither** `if` condition is satisfied"

Comment: No problem - normally I wouldn't worry about such things, but here it actually affected the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way:

```
public bool GetCollision(int x, int y)
{
    bool isPassable = false;

    if (y < 0 || y >= 20)
    {
        isPassable = true;
    }

    return isPassable;
}
```

This way, you can make sure that it returns **true** only when this condition is met, otherwise it returns just **false**.

Answer (score 0):

You should've a default-value:

```
bool isPassable = false;
```

If you can't exactly say, whether it's true or false, use `nullable values` instead, so `isPassable` can be null:

```
public bool? GetCollision(int x, int y)
{
    bool? isPassable = null;

    if (x < 0 || x >= 20)
    {
        isPassable = false;
    }

    if (y < 0 || y >= 20)
    {
        isPassable = true;
    }

    return isPassable;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that would work? I can't test now, but I believe this too would require `isPassable` to be assigned, before the error would go away. The only difference is that you can assign `null` if you want.

Comment: Yeah. Now that you say that, I'm not sure, too. I'll edit the answer.